# How do I edit the styles.xml of a dependency in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, showcaseview

**How do I edit the styles.xml of a dependency in Android Studio?**

Im currently using [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) 5.0 , but i want to theme the styles xml to what my ui colors look like. but i dont see any styles.xml associated from maven dependency.

Default theme i think
[image]

Any kind of technique is greatly appreciated,

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to edit the styles.xml, just provide your own. Take a look at the sample app, which has its own ShowcaseView styles:

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: one more thing, how can i change the color of the subtext under title?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because I don't have >50 reputation.

You can change your parent class in your style in which to inherit from.  If you switch in between ShowcaseView.Light and ShowcaseView the detail text should alternate between white/black.

OR you might be able to use this in your style:

```
<item name="sv_detailTextAppearance">@style/CustomDetailText</item>
```

Comment: hey where have you seen the item name? Ive been looking all over for it. thanks by the way. :)